# React Error Cannot find module './lib/api/node.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, create-react-app

I've cloned my react project from a git repository and after running `npm install` to install my dependencies (and then install other missing global dependencies) I tried running it with `npm run start` only to get the following error : `Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module './lib/api/node.js'` and I can;t understand what is wrong with it.Can anyone help me out?
 I have to mention that I've used `npm eject` on this project
Thanks in advance !

Here is my package.json :

```
    {
  "name": "asezarile-rupestre",
  "version": "0.3.3-pre",
 "private": false,
 "dependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
"babel-core": "6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
"babel-jest": "20.0.3",
"babel-loader": "7.1.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
"babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
"chalk": "1.1.3",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
"create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
"css-loader": "0.28.7",
"dotenv": "4.0.0",
"dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
"eslint": "4.10.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
"eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"file-loader": "1.1.5",
"fs-extra": "3.0.1",
"glyphicons": "^0.2.0",
"google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
"jest": "20.0.4",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"object-assign": "4.1.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.4",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
"postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
"promise": "8.0.1",
"raf": "3.4.0",
"react": "^16.4.2",
"react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.32.3",
"react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
"react-dom": "^16.4.2",
"react-iframe": "^1.2.0",
"react-load-script": "0.0.6",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
"react-unity-webgl": "^7.0.6",
"resolve": "1.6.0",
"style-loader": "0.19.0",
"sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
"url-loader": "0.6.2",
"webpack": "3.8.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.3",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
"whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
   },
   "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
   },
  "jest": {
   "collectCoverageFrom": [
     "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
     ],
   "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
   ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "web.js",
  "js",
  "json",
  "web.jsx",
  "jsx",
  "node",
  "mjs"
]
  },
     "babel": {
   "presets": [
     "react-app"
   ]
   },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by using `eject` and not setting up configuration for Webpack. If you want to avoid using `eject`, take a look at [react app rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). This will allow you to use create react app and also customize it.

Answer (score 0):

after ruining npm eject you are taking the control of webpack into your hand. you have to configure the webpack manually.

Comment: Oh.... Is it a hard config to make myself in order to fix the error or I should create a new project without eject

Comment: create a new project with create-react app, later you can easily make a production build and do the testing.